# Insert WhiteSpaces and remove last characters from string

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2010

I need a prepared string for my Visual Studio 2010 macro. The string should be the document name (`document.Name`) but without the file extension (for example `.cs`) and after each upper case should be a white space.

**Example:**

```
document.Name = TestFileName.cs
```

**How can I get this:**

```
"Test File Name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For trivial cases (non consecutive upper-case):

```
file = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
file = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(file, "([a-z0-9])([A-Z])", "$1 $2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic framework

```
String PreString = "getAllItemsByID";

System.Text.StringBuilder SB = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

foreach (Char C in PreString)
{
    if (Char.IsUpper(C))
        SB.Append(' ');
    SB.Append(C);
}

Response.Write(SB.ToString());
```

You may need to add a few checks:-When the very first char is Uppercase not to add a space.-When a word like ID is encountered, remove the last space.

**[OR try this]**

This will find each occurance of a lower case character followed by an upper case character, and insert a space between them:

```
s = s.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
```

Comment: Yes, or else you could try the regex.